# How to get a Scheme from chemmacros floats inside a section?

Tags: floats, sectioning, chemmacros

Currently I'm struggling with a weird problem. 
I use the `chemmacros` package to provide the `\scheme` float enviroment for my  chemical schemes. Then I use `\FloatBarrier` to prevent them from floating away too far. 
Now there should be a specific layout where I have my sectionheading then the picture and then the text.
So my code looks like this:

```
\documentclass[a4, english]{scrreprt}
\begin{document}
\section{Synthesis A}
\FloatBarrier
\begin{scheme}[h]
\includegraphics
\end{scheme}

Here some text

\end{document}
```

For some reason I have cases, where it works out totally fine, in other samples, the warning "h specified to ht" comes up and I have the scheme on the page, then the heading of the section or subsection then the text.

I know that Float enviroments are there to float not to be restricted but this drives me mad. So I'm looking for a workaround. Can I place a picture just by `\includegraphics{}` and then still add a label and a caption to it leaving out the float environment?

I heard of the package `captionof` which might provide some help?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is quite easy, actually, and you're on the right track: don't use the floating environment. I'd probably use `center` instead.

You can still caption the image with `\captionof` which is available in each KOMA-Script class like `scrreprt` that you're already using*:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usechemmodule{scheme}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{Synthesis A}

\begin{center}
  \includegraphics{example-image-a}
  \captionof{scheme}{Some caption}
\end{center}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

* users of other classes can use the `caption` package which also provides `\captionof`.